# In lambda, Could not parse request body into json

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I try to make backend with lambda.

So I make the sample of it and post the data by postman.

I select form-data and put data in key and value.

and it returns like that.

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'Idx\': was expecting \'null\', \'true\', \'false\' or NaN\n at [Source: [B@745d4999; line: 1, column: 5]"}
```

So I find the some of docs, if I use postman to test lambda, select row and post the data like

```
{
   "key" : "params"
}
```

But I want to receive the data in lambda when I post the data by form-data type.

---

It is simple test of it
In lambda,

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement

    const Idx = event.Idx * 2;


    callback(null, Idx);

};
```

and, when I post the data json type
[image]
and when I post the data form-data type
[image]

Comment: Please include the source for the area that the error refers to.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I edit my answer of that.

Answer (score 0):

When using form data your event.body is not a JSON, it’s a string that you need to parse. Specifically, it’s a query string. So in your case, it is:`Idx=2`
What you need to do is parse it to a JSON and then operate on it.
You can use a module for that

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
```

And inside the lambda

```
const body = querystring.parse(event.body)
```

Now you can access the `Idx` using `body[‘Idx’]`

You can use `typeof` to differentiate if it is an object or a string like so:

```
if (typeof(event.body) === ‘object’)
```

Edit: full code

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    console.log(event.body);
    var Idx = null;
    if (typeof(event.body) === ‘object’) {
        Idx = event.Idx * 2; 
    } else if (typeof(event.body) === ‘string’) {
        Idx = querystring.parse(event.body)[‘Idx’];
    }
    callback(null, Idx);
};
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for late response of your answer. I try this, but same message : Could not parse request body into json @Khanal

Comment: Can you try the latest edit? This should be the full code replacement to what you have posted. Then if you still run into an error, can you post what the value of event.body was? It’s being logged now.

Comment: Yes I try the lastest edit. Same issue, Could not parse @Khanal

Comment: Did you check the console logs, what does event.body equal to in the logs?

Comment: I found why this message occur. when I post the data by postman, I use the api gateway. So I change the body mapping templates, It takes the data. Thank you for your answer. Have a nice day @Khanal